# Changing color of gradient background (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background

I'm trying to change the color of a gradient background in kind of a trippy manner (The colors are going to be weird)

I wrote the code below but i dont understand why I cant change the background color at all.

```
var start1 = [0,216,255];
var start2 = [50,255,224];
setInterval(function (){
    $("body").css("background", "-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, from(rgb("+start1[0]+", "+start1[1]+", "+start1[2]+")), to(rgb("+start2[0]+", "+start2[1]+", "+start2[2]+")));");
    start1[0] = checknumber(start1[0]+1);
    start1[1] = checknumber(start1[1]+1);
    start1[2] = checknumber(start1[2]+1);
    start2[0] = checknumber(start1[0]+1);
    start2[1] = checknumber(start1[1]+1);
    start2[2] = checknumber(start1[2]+1);
},100);
```

I dont get any errors and the background only stays white. I'm guessing it's going to be a little more complicated than I imagined

The the `checknumber()` function just checks if the number is greater than 255- if it is then it resets back at 0.

Comment: It would be *much* simpler to setup a CSS class for this, and then just use `addClass()` on the `body` element.

Comment: a fiddle would make it easy to help you

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/4nuhpmov/

The issue was your CSS syntax, I think you may have been using an old reference.

I changed the CSS manipulation JavaScript as follows:

```
$("body").css("background",
    "linear-gradient(" + degrees + "deg, rgba(" + start1[0] + ", " + start1[1] + ", " + start1[2] + ", 1),  rgba(" + start2[0] + ", " + start2[1] + ", " + start2[2] + ", 1))");
```

I also added a counter for degrees.

This is probably not the best way to do this but it should get you started (I don't think it's as trippy/crazy as you expected but you can play around with the values).

You can use the following link to find the most up-to-date syntax:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient